# Loading a PHP script from a DIV

Tags: php, javascript, html

Can I please have some help to load a PHP file from a DIV call.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">

        $("#LoadPHP").load("fb_marketing.php");

    </script>
    <div id="LoadPHP">Load PHP Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you cannot tell what I am trying to do, I will explain it. Basically, I am wanting to load the 'fb_marketing.php' file when a reference is made to a DIV on a webpage.

The above code is not working. Can I please have some help to get it working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just do `<div><?PHP include('fb_marketing.php'); ?></div>`?

Comment: you can use include, require, include_once, or even for running a php code part you can use eval functions.

Comment: Also note when your script runs, there is no `LoadPHP` element yet.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not that bad, and it's a first timer question too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing your jQuery library. In order to call the `load` function which is a part of the jQuery library, you need to include the library in your `head`.

Furthermore, I would wait until the entire DOM is loaded first by wrapping the code in a `$.ready(function() { //code here });` method.

Comment: From [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) add this line into the `<head>` section: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div id="LoadPHP">
<?php
echo "this is where your php would go";
?>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="LoadPHP">
<?php
include 'testPHP.php';
?>    
</div>
```